# how do i get similar lines out of two files?

Tags: python, scripting, grep

I want to compare two files. file1.txt file2.txt

file1.txt

```
name1
name2
name3
```

file2.txt

```
nameA
nameB
name1
nameC
```

i want to use grep to look at the two files and say name1 is in both files. 
how do i do this?

Comment: If you want to use grep, why do you tag python then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

From man:

> -f FILE, --file=FILE
>                 Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is
>   specified by POSIX.)

Comment: Seeing as the lines aren't regular expressions, the fixed string option is probably a good idea too: `-F`

Answer (score 1):

Using `comm(1)` :

```
 comm -1 -2 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
name1
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

`-1 -2 means to suppress column 1 & 2, and keeping only the intersect.

---

> NAME
>
> ```
>     comm - compare two sorted files line by line
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-f` option in `grep` to feed the first file in as a "file of patterns", and perform `grep` on the second file as the actual search space:

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

Breakdown:

- `grep`: invoke the grep tool
- `-f file1.txt`: specify `file1.txt` as the file that holds your search patterns
- `file2.txt`: name of the file to be used for your search space.

Answer (score 0):

Set is useful in python for comparing lists.

```
>>> f1 = set( l.strip() for l in open('file1.txt'))
>>> f2 = set( l.strip() for l in open('file2.txt'))
>>> print "\n".join( f1 & f2)
name1
```

It can also generate the diffs too:

```
>>> print "\n".join( f1 - f2)
name2
name3
>>> print "\n".join( f2 - f1)
nameB
nameC
nameA
```

As Suggested by @Jon Clements if you're concerned with performance use this form:

```
 f1 = set( l.strip() for l in open('file1.txt'))
 common = f1.intersection(l for l in open('file2.txt'))
 print "\n".join( common )
```

It is more memory efficient and faster as it does not store the content of "file2.txt" in memory.

Comment: You don't need f2 to be a `set` - you can just use `f1.intersection(el.strip() for el in open('file2.txt'))` to save memory usage...

Comment: Thanks Jon I didn't read "Note, the non-operator versions of union(), intersection(), difference(), and symmetric_difference(), issubset(), and issuperset() methods will accept any iterable as an argument." http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff to compare files.

`diff file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: Mhhhh ? Shot in the water. OP asked the opposite.